# dos command flex core

Tags: apache-flex, command

Can I execute some dos like command from Flex just like
`attrib c:\a.txt -h`.

Function available in C `exec()`, in Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.
But in Flex is there any available?

Comment: I supposed from  the "c:\" that it was client side, but good question...

Comment: only from client side AIR application

Comment: only from client side AIR application no server side

Comment: You could try AIR 2 beta in which support for this is added. However, I guess this is only useful if your app is only for your own use... can't really rely on beta. See i.e. http://corlan.org/2009/11/30/magnifying-glass-air-2-application-or-how-to-communicate-with-a-java-program-from-air/

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you're going to come to achieving this is by using [fscommand()](http://flash-reference.icod.de/global_functions.html#fscommand%28%29), which has quite a few limitations.

Remember that Flex applications run in the Flash player (usually within a browser) and thus don't typically have access to shell commands of the host filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

> Two of the most requested features for
>   Adobe AIR have been the ability to
>   launch native executables from an AIR
>   application, and the ability to
>   integrate native libraries into an AIR
>   application. Unfortunately, neither
>   feature will be included in Adobe AIR
>   1.0.

But **there is a workaround**. It's a *bit complicated*, yet elegant, and should solve your problem. It relies on [CommandProxy](http://code.google.com/p/commandproxy/), a kit for proxying calls between applications and the operating system. You will find [here a detailed article](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/) on how to implement this solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run batch files using flex..then do the following
var file:File =new File(path to batch file)
//do not give the .bat extension only file name is reqiured.
file.openWithDefaultApplication();
// the batch file will open and run the dos commands you have written